# Can you make the `dd` command safe?

Tags: command-line, command, dd, bashrc, arguments

We all have (or know someone who has) unintentionally misused the `destroy-disk` ([`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix))) command. What ways exist (if any) to change the command in the following or a similar way: If `/dev/sda` is given as the output file (`of=/dev/sda`) the command doesn't run or prompts for confirmation with something like "are you sure about that"?

Could you achieve something like that using your `.bashrc`  file?

Is there a way, in general, to stop certain commands from running when certain arguments are passed?

**Edit**: The command is run as root.

Comment: You can create a wrapper and put it in your `$PATH`.

Comment: they will just invent a better idiot who will find some new way to turn the power tool `dd` into a footgun

Comment: There is no way to prevent people from screwing things up.  Don't give user access to login as root, and don't put them in the 'disk' group?  Just have good backup system so you can recover things when people make errors?  Any attempt to filter things will probably break commands/scripts that use dd.

Comment: Make something idiot proof, and some moron will come along with a better idiot.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk feel free to elaborate on wrappers for commands in an answer!

Comment: Install `ddrescue` and make a global `alias dd='ddrescue'` to have it run instead of `dd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Arkadiusz said, you can create a wrapper:

```
dd() {
  # Limit variables' scope
  local args command output reply

  # Basic arguments handling
  while (( ${#} > 0 )); do
    case "${1}" in
    ( of=* )
      output="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    ( * )
      args+=( "${1}" )
      ;;
    esac
    shift || break
  done

  # Build the actual command
  command=( command -- dd "${args[@]}" "of=${output}" )

  # Warn the user
  printf 'Please double-check this to avoid potentially dangerous behavior.\n' >&2
  printf 'Output file: %s\n' "${output}" >&2

  # Ask for confirmation
  IFS= read -p 'Do you want to continue? (y/n): ' -r reply

  # Check user's reply
  case "${reply}" in
  ( y | yes )
    printf 'Running command...\n' >&2
    ;;
  ( * )
    printf 'Aborting\n' >&2
    return
    ;;
  esac

  # Run command
  "${command[@]}"
}
```

Example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt bs=4M count=5
Please double-check this to avoid potentially dangerous behavior.
Output file: file.txt
Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
Running command...
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
20971520 bytes (21 MB, 20 MiB) copied, 0.443037 s, 47.3 MB/s
```

Modify it to fit your needs (make it POSIX-compliant, check for other conditions, etc).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, a non-superuser cannot overwrite `/dev/sda`.  If you can't trust your operators who have been entrusted with superuser access, you have larger problems than `/bin/dd`.

Comment: The assumption is that the command is run as root

Comment: Firstly, the assumption was not made in the question.  Please edit the question to clarify.  Secondly, the problem still exists.  There are myriad ways for a superuser to destroy a system with tools not meant to be so destructive.  I could readily come up with ten examples.  You need to fix your users, not the tools at their disposal.

Comment: The havoc you can make with a simple `rm -rf /some/important/directory` (read `man rm`!!)...  ^_^;